# Why does WAMP says this:"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."?

Tags: html, windows, wamp

So I installed WAMP on Windows 7 and port-forwarded my Privat IP and I tried using my Public IP, but no luck.It's just giving me this error:   Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.I tested it out with localhost and 127.0.0.1 and it worked, but with my Public Ip it dosen't.Please Help me!

Comment: Check the error logs, and let us know what they say.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y1xhZtjG

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the settings in you httpd.conf file. To correct the problem, follow the steps-

1. Click on the wamp icon.
2. Go to, Apache -> httpd.conf
3. Now search for "Controls who can get stuff from this server."
4. See below that, there should be a line "Deny from all".
5. Change it to "Allow from all".

Comment: Could also be an error in .htaccess if there is one

Comment: Maybe, but I also had the same error and got it right in this way. If you would access your website using url: localhost or 127.0.0.1 then it should open your website correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To allow your Apache server to be accessed from the internet you need to tell Apache that it is allowed to accept connections from any IP address

Edit `httpd.conf` using the wampmanager menus links.

Find this snippet in the config file

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
```

And as you are using Apache 2.4.x change it to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```